# Trying to install Node.js in Debian Jessie breaks packages

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, installation, apt

I'm running Debian Jessie (8.5) and trying to install Node.js:
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

It's become quite a rabbit hole. The above command gave me the error:

`nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable`

apt-get didn't seem to know anything about rlwrap, because `apt-cache search rlwrap` didn't come up with anything. So I downloaded the package (`rlwrap-0.42`) manually, and trying to run `./configure` on it gave the following:

`You need the GNU readline library(ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/ ) to build
this program!`

So I installed `libreadline`, and that didn't make the error go away, but I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194523/how-do-i-install-gnu-readline) that `libreadline-dev` is needed too. Again `apt-cache search` came up with nothing, so I downloaded the package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libreadline-dev) (packages.ubuntu.com).

The debian package installer told me:

`Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libtinfo-dev`

So I tried downloading and installing `libtinfo-dev`. That one said that it needed `libtinfo5`. Then, `libtinfo5` gave me the following:

`Error: breaks existing package 'libncurses5' dependency libtinfo5 (= 5.9 +20140913-1 +b1)`

And now I'm stuck. How can I resolve this package issue? Or is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: an image of my terminal window after doing an `apt-get update` and then `apt-cache search rlwrap`

[image]

Comment: I managed to solve this (on Debian 8.2) using a different version of Node.js: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -` and then `apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were able to install `rlwrap` manually, `apt-get` would still consider it an unmet dependency (it will search for the *package* `rlwrap`, not for the executable). The fact that `apt-cache search rlwrap` comes up empty is suspicious, as `rlwrap` [is in Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/utils/rlwrap). Did you do an `apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes, I did `apt-get update`. I think the fact that `apt-cache search rlwap` comes up as empty is suspicious too. I edited my post to add a shot of my terminal after an `apt-get update` and an `apt-cache search rlwrap` I don't have any ideas as to why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps, taken from screenshot:

[image: screencap of steps to try]

Comment: In the future, you should actually write out the steps, not paste a screenshot (which then needs to be typed in by people wishing to try). Also, be sure to properly embed the image, so that people see it (see my edits).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's just I cannot paste more than 1 link in comment, so make a screenshot of the solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer! These steps didn't work - I ended up getting the same error - `nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable.` Can you explain what the steps in your answer are doing? I'd like to understand.